# Get Data from Table with Column as Rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

Can any one help me with a query that converts column into rows and then find data accordingly.

The question is below. I have tried a query that gets the column names into rows but i was unable to get values or had any idea to figure it out for column3 and column 4. I am a new bibe in SQL. Can anyone help me out here. I heard from a friend suggesting pivot and when i browse i found PIVOT is not supported in MYSQL

```
Input Table: 

E1           E2           E3           E4           E5           E6

Null         1234         234          12           A            B
123          Null         Null         Null         12           B
Null         Null         Null         Null         Null         Null
123          2            1            A            1            2


Output Table:

C1           C2           Count           TotalC           percent           

E1           123          2               2                1
E2           1234         1               2                0.5
E2           2            1               2                0.5
E3           234          1               2                0.5
E3           1            1               2                0.5
E4           12           1               2                0.5
E4           A            1               2                0.5
E5           A            1               3                0.3
E5           12           1               3                0.3
E5           1            1               3                0.3
E6           B            2               3                0.6
E6           2            1               3                0.3
```

Explanation of the Question:

1. C1 is the Column names of input table.
2. C2 is the data in those columns.
3. Count is the number of similar items and singles in each columns.
4. TotalC is the number of total not null values.
5. percent is the count/totalc.

Query i worked : `SELECT (COLUMN_NAME)AS Column1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'inputtable';`

Note: query in MYSQL.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this?  Can you provide some more context?  Chances are either that this task is better performed outside of your database layer, or you would be better off using a different schema.

Comment: @eggyal: ill get a file with that sample data as input and i have to run query to get data to persist in the other table. And may i know what do you mean by "outside of your database layer ".

Comment: By "*outside of the database layer*", I mean to perform this data manipulation in your application code, rather than in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, you should probably handle this problem differently.  See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

However, if you must, you can solve this problem using [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html):

```
SELECT *, Count/TotalC AS percent
FROM (
  SELECT   'E1' AS C1, E1 AS C2, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM     Input
  WHERE    E1 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY C2
UNION ALL
  SELECT   'E2' AS C1, E2 AS C2, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM     Input
  WHERE    E2 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY C2
UNION ALL
  SELECT   'E3' AS C1, E3 AS C2, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM     Input
  WHERE    E3 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY C2
UNION ALL
  SELECT   'E4' AS C1, E4 AS C2, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM     Input
  WHERE    E4 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY C2
UNION ALL
  SELECT   'E5' AS C1, E5 AS C2, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM     Input
  WHERE    E5 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY C2
UNION ALL
  SELECT   'E6' AS C1, E6 AS C2, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM     Input
  WHERE    E6 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY C2
) t1 NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT 'E1' AS C1, COUNT(E1) AS TotalC FROM Input
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E2' AS C1, COUNT(E2) AS TotalC FROM Input
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E3' AS C1, COUNT(E3) AS TotalC FROM Input
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E4' AS C1, COUNT(E4) AS TotalC FROM Input
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E5' AS C1, COUNT(E5) AS TotalC FROM Input
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E6' AS C1, COUNT(E6) AS TotalC FROM Input
) t2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f54d/1/0).

Comment: I am struggling out to make it dynamic. Is there any way where i could get E1, E2, E3................................ as dynamic.

Comment: @AnveshVejandla: [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/columns-table.html)?